# Dificuldade para relacionar os municípios do SNIS com os do IBGE

Tags: banco-de-dados, integração

Estou tentando querendo montar uma base de dados que inclua a população atendida pelos serviço de saneamento e o PIB per per capita de cada município. O primeiro dado eu já consegui acessar pelo SNIS. O segunda dado fica disponível no IBGE e também já tenho ele em mãos.

Todavia, o sistema do IBGE não usa o código dos municípios. Já os dados do SNIS tem uma coluna com o código dos municípios, mas não é o mesmo número de outras bases de dados - contém apenas 6 dígitos. Me parece que a única alternativa seria agregar os dados pelo nome dos municípios, o que eu não sei fazer e poderia gerar infinitas incongruências.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria muito agradecido.

Comment: Pergunta, não seria melhor você atribuir um `id` para cada município, juntamente com o nome do mesmo, em uma tabela pai, e depois duas tabelas filhas, uma para atribuir o PIB ao id do município respectivo, e outra tabela para lançar a população atendida pelo saneamento básico, também atribuindo ao id do município?

Answer (score 2):

Há vários municípios brasileiros que têm o mesmo nome, pensei que eram poucos, mas ao [conferir a lista de todos eles](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_munic%C3%ADpios_do_Brasil), vi que são muitos os casos. Acho que o pior caso é Bom Jesus, nome de um município do Piauí, um do Rio Grande do Norte, um da Paraíba, um de Santa Catarina e um do Rio Grande do Sul. Há outros nomes que só divergem na acentuação, tal como Arapuá (MG) e Arapuã (PR).

Entretanto, um estado não pode ter dois municípios com um mesmo nome e nem dois municípios que só diferem na acentuação. Assim sendo se você puder obter o nome ou a sigla do estado de cada município e concatenar ao nome, cada nome de município será único.

Pode ser que haja diferenças referentes a maiúsculas e minúsculas, acentos e apóstrofos. Por exemplo, uma base pode te dar "*Olho d'Água das Cunhãs (MA)*" e a outra "*OLHO DAGUA DAS CUNHAS (MA)*". Neste caso você converte tudo para maiúsculas, tira os acentos e tira os apóstrofos para unificar o nome.

Assim sendo, se você puder obter das bases o nome, sigla ou código do estado junto com o nome do município, então **basta relacionar-se os nomes dos municípios junto com os estados** para você fazer esse mapeamento <sup>[solução 1]</sup>.

Se você não consegue obter o nome, sigla ou código do estado diretamente, pode ser que ele seja parte do código do município. Por exemplo, os dois primeiros dígitos do código do município utilizado pelo IBGE nas bases que conheço são os mesmos dígitos do estado. Não sei como são os dados do SNIS que você está utilizando, mas acho que seja apenas o código do município do IBGE sem o último dígito, pois pelo menos é isso que eu encontrei ao procurar alguns arquivos para download no site do SNIS.

Desprezar-se o último dígito do código do IBGE é seguro, uma vez que este é apenas um dígito verificador. Pelo que verifiquei nas planilhas que achei no site do SNIS, é exatamente esse o caso. Por exemplo, o município de Americana tem o código do IBGE 3501608, e na planilha que achei em algum lugar do site do SNIS consta o código 350160. Nos dois casos, 35 é o código do estado de São Paulo. **Neste caso, basta desconsiderar o último dígito do código do IBGE e os códigos vão coincidir.** <sup>[solução 2]</sup>

Caso o seu código seja alguma coisa que não tenha similaridade com o código do IBGE e você não tem a informação do estado disponível de forma direta, então mesmo assim você deve tentar achar um padrão que a partir do código você descubra o estado. Se esse padrão não existir, então você dança, pois neste caso, não será capaz de saber quem é quem no caso de Bom Jesus, por exemplo. Entretanto, acho improvável que a base do SNIS que você está usando relacione o município sem informar absolutamente nada do estado em questão.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo ontem tem essa coisa é no site sidra. Eh bem dificil achar o link dos dowloads de base de dados. Mas verifique se essa t3m tudo que voce precisa
[Download sidra atualizado municipios](http://www.sidra.ibge.gov.br/bda/territorio/download/munic.xls)